# (Possible Spoilers) In Hortensia Saga, why can't the princess just return to the castle?

Tags: hortensia-saga

In *Hortensia Saga*, I understand that the castle was attacked, but they said in the anime that her brother was on the throne and that she was missing.

So if her brother is on the throne, can't that uncle Maurice call some guards or knights and escort her to the palace? There are no enemies at the palace, so why hide her for four years?

Answer (score 1):

From what transpired of the last episode (episode 3). The church seems to have been taking control of the power by basically controlling her brother. At the moment, the standing of the church is not super clear and we don't really know if they are involved in any of this.

From the characters point of view:

- When the king was alive and the country was strong, he got killed.
- Since her brother took throne and followed the church nothing has happened to him.

It wouldn't be wrong to imagine that by going back and taking the throne, she could either: do what the church says and stay alive or follow her father footsteps and probably get killed too.

I think it's a pretty smart move to wait few years and see the direction the country is taking before making any public claim to the throne. Also, being close to somebody who can raise a small army and control lands opens up a lot of options.

Judging by her past decisions, all this thinking has probably been done by the old man. I am convinced that, if she was given the opportunity, she would rush to the castle to ensure the well-being of her brother.